# How to get dynamic array value using check box in angular.Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to get value of check box using angular =. I have java object at HTML page. As user checked individual box so singe value should be in my array, if user check select all so all box should be checked and array should be contain all checked boxes value, and it should be unchecked when select all is unchecked. Here is the code please suggest me some solution.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Select All">
<label>
     <c:forEach items="${sellerProductsDto.sellerProductColorsDtos}"  var="colors">
     <input type="checkbox" value="${colors.keyId}" ng-model=""> ${colors.colorName}
        </c:forEach>
</label>
```

Comment: show us your angular code

Comment: Controller side code please

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande  i am not sure about my controller side code ,  i am looking for controller side function for get value, i was trying to get the value using n-model but i am unable to pass java object into the ng-model.

Comment: @RameshRajendran If you could give me some idea about controller side function so it will be great. I tried many things but it's not working

Comment: i want checked box id as  value.

Comment: $scope.changeColor = function(value, colorId) {
 $scope.colorKeyId = colorId;
}; 
   I was trying to call function at 
ng-change="changeColor(true, '${colors.keyId}')"

Answer (score 0):

This might help. It's providing directive for checkboxlist

```
https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/
```

Check demo

```
http://jsfiddle.net/yasirzuberi/r1Lc3ba0/4/
```